# Date format in c# with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting a date value from MySQL and I am trying to format it so it doesn't have any spaces or show the time. When I bring it in as a string I get the full date and time so I thought I would try the convert.TODateTime format that I read in another post but it doesnt seem to be working.

the end goals is to get the date to show as only the number with no spaces or dashes e.g 21/02/1982 would be 21021982.

the error I get is 'Could not find the specified column in results s5'

Can someone please point me in the right direction

```
public MySqlDataReader RunQueryNATFiles27(string query, string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5, string s6, string s7, string s8, string s9, string s10, string s11, string s12, string s13, string s14, string s15, string s16, string s17, string s18, string s19, string s20, string s21, string s22, string s23, string s24, string s25, string s26, string s27, string pathName, string NATFile)
{
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@pathName);
    conDataBase.Open();
    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {


        string NameHolder1 = (myReader[s1].ToString());
        string NameHolder2 = (myReader[s2].ToString());
        string NameHolder3 = (myReader[s3].ToString());
        string NameHolder4 = (myReader[s4].ToString());


       var NameHolder5 = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["s5"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        // NameHolder5 =  String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", NameHolder5);

        MessageBox.Show(NameHolder5);


        string NameHolder6 = (myReader[s6].ToString());
        string NameHolder7 = (myReader[s7].ToString());
        string NameHolder8 = (myReader[s8].ToString());
        string NameHolder9 = (myReader[s9].ToString());
        string NameHolder10 = (myReader[s10].ToString());
        string NameHolder11 = (myReader[s11].ToString());
        string NameHolder12 = (myReader[s12].ToString());
        string NameHolder13 = (myReader[s13].ToString());
        string NameHolder14 = (myReader[s14].ToString());
        string NameHolder15 = (myReader[s15].ToString());
        string NameHolder16 = (myReader[s16].ToString());
        string NameHolder17 = (myReader[s17].ToString());
        string NameHolder18 = (myReader[s18].ToString());
        string NameHolder19 = (myReader[s19].ToString());
        string NameHolder20 = (myReader[s20].ToString());
        string NameHolder21 = (myReader[s21].ToString());
        string NameHolder22 = (myReader[s22].ToString());
        string NameHolder23 = (myReader[s23].ToString());
        string NameHolder24 = (myReader[s24].ToString());
        string NameHolder25 = (myReader[s25].ToString());
        string NameHolder26 = (myReader[s26].ToString());
        string NameHolder27 = (myReader[s27].ToString());
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(myReader[s5]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` => should it be this? `myReader["s5"]` tries returning value from a column named "s5" instead of the column name stored in `s5` string variable.

Comment: The specified error(`Could not find the specified column in results s5`) is not because of formatting `DateTime`, its says you haven't fetched a column named `s5`.

Comment: this is a function, the column name gets passed to it, which in this case is "DATE OF BIRTH" - it works fine except for the incorrect formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query and retrieve your dates in the format `ddMMYYYY`, you can actually handle this on the MySQL side using the `DATE_FORMAT` function, e.g.

```
SELECT
    Student_Number,
    first_name,
    DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d%m%Y') AS DOB
FROM STUDENTREGISTER;
```

This would yield `01022014` as the output.  `DATE_FORMAT` returns a string, so your C# code should be expected a string for the `DOB` column.

Comment: where abouts in the SQL do I put that,  this is my current SQL "SELECT `Student Number`, `first name`,'DOB  FROM `STUDENT REGISTER`

Comment: when I use it in phpmyadmin it works but in C# I get the error message Could not find specified column in results  DATE OF BRITH'

Comment: The query you are running is NOT what is in my answer.  Just alias `DATE_FORMAT` as `DOB` and then use this column in your C# code.

Comment: I am such a fool! I was leaving the alias part out to avoid confusion not knowing that was the critical part. Thank you so Much. I have spent over 3 hours with this!